# Command to list branches on particular server

Tags: git

Currently, I have two servers 'origin' and 'stash'. If I've to see all branches respective to 'stash' or 'origin' server, how can I see? Following command lists branches on all servers:

```
git branch -a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
git remote show <remote-name>
```

there is a section called "remote branches". It lists the branches of this remote.

Another option is to use `grep` with `git branch -r`

```
git branch -r | grep '<remote-name>/'
```

.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept answer in 6 mins since I can accept it after 6 mins(checked clicking on 'accept')